# Is there a global map of wind design loads or wind gust climatology?

Tags: climate, wind, mapping, data-analysis

I'm looking for a world map of wind gust climatology data, with the specific purpose of being used for coarse comparison of building design loads, with a consistent metric regardless of location.

Ideally it would be very similar to what's used in building codes, such as "basic wind speed" in ASCE 7 for the US & International Building Code, and comparable codes for other regions:  a contour map or heat map of  the max value with a 50-year return period (or similar statistic, with various levels for different risk profiles).  See the US map [here](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IBC2018/chapter-16-structural-design#IBC2018_Ch16_Sec1609.3) and one for India (below, [source](https://skyciv.com/docs/tech-notes/loading/is-875-3-wind-load-calculation-example/)).
[image: map of IS 875-3 wind loads]

I have found world maps of other climatology and extreme value data, but none for high-percentile gusts. Most of the global wind data maps are oriented towards power generation.  I'm not sure what resolution I need, probably 1- or 2- degree would be fine, but it would have to come from a higher-resolution source to capture local maxima.

What I've already tried/considered:

- The closest I've found is [this Dlubal seismic/wind/snow load map explorer](https://www.dlubal.com/en-US/solutions/online-services/snow-load-wind-speed-and-seismic-load-maps) - which is super useful and impressive, but doesn't fully serve my need because it's (a) a limited-click web app of a paid program, not a static map or set of maps, (b) does not have all countries, and (c) uses local codes which vary, making initial comparisons hard -although they would be needed eventually.
- I would make my own if I had more time to spend.  The data is there at a useful level in several climate re-analysis products, such as MERRA-2 and ERA-5.  In particular the Copernicus CDS not only lets you slice and download datasets, but even [do the analysis online](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/toolbox).  I tried to use Panoply to create a view for a single timestep, but simply don't have the experience and time to efficiently do the 24 hr x 365 day x 30 year x 10<sup>6</sup> gridpoints analysis.

Any pointers are welcome (including on this, my first StackExchange question). Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I hoppe you can post more questions. I hoppe too you receive an answer! Welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out [Global Wind Atlas](https://globalwindatlas.info/). It uses ERA5 reanalysis data then plugs it into meso and microscale models to get it down to a 250x250m grid.

Comment: Thank you - this is an interesting site with great resolution in time and space for mean wind speeds.  However - and perhaps I missed it - I don't see wind extremes on here, which is the core of my question. Is there a way to get that data (i.e. maximum gust speed in a given time period) from this site?

Comment: When you click a certain location on the map, it brings up some key information. Which includes a distribution of wind speeds. (percentile buckets). You can export that information out as well.